# DynDNS alternative for TCP traffic forwarding?

Tags: dynamic, static, dns, ip, dyndns

I have a dynamic IP address and require a static one and am looking for a free solution; DynDNS only forwards http traffic, not TCP, I need a solution that would forward to the specified TCP port with a static sub-domain or IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynDNS isn't forwarding; it's just putting your IP address in the DNS tables.  Any app should be able to use that IP address on any port (provided there is no firewall, etc.)  I use my DynDNS addresses for all sorts of non-http applications.